# how to send a secound value in autocomplete ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Good afternoon, I’m trying jQuery ajax autocomplete for the first time and it seems to be working great but I have found my self in a bit of problem, you see I have a sql table name 
Clients: with the following columns, id_client , clinent_name ,  id_user,
Basically each table is assigned to a user . and that’s where my problem comes 
in index.php I have the following code :

```
           <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
               $("#name").autocomplete({
               source: "/cliente.php",
              minLength: 1,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#client_name').val(ui.item.client_name);
                $('#id_client').val(ui.item.id_cliente);   })});
            </script>
```

Which sends the value of the input with the name =’name’ to cliente.php

```
    if (isset($_GET['term'])){
     include 'include/conexion.php';
       $return_arr = array();
     if ($con)
          {
    $fetch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cliente where name like '%" . 
    mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_GET['term'])) . "%' LIMIT 0 ,50"); 
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {
     $id_cliente=$row['id_cliente'];
    $row_array['value'] = $row['id_client']." | ".$row['cliente_name']; a 
     rray_push($return_arr,$row_array);   }} mysqli_close($con); echo json_encode($return_arr);}
```

**But the problem is I’m trying to send another value to cliente.php which is id_user so the user could only look up clients assign to them.**

Comment: You should be keeping that information in a session variable on the server as it is easy for a user to change any value submitted from the client side.

Comment: hey that probably the way to go ill try it

Answer (score 0):

In PHP. we have to change the row array.

```
$row_array['value'] = $row['id_client']." | ".$row['cliente_name'];  =>
$row_array[] =  $row['id_client']." | ".$row['cliente_name'];
```

In js, we have to parse the return value. Label and value are the same in autocomplete success callback.

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var values= ui.item.value.split("|");
    if (values.length > 1) {
        $('#client_name').val(values[1]);
        $('#id_client').val(values[0]);
    }
}
```